# Flattening map<string,string> column in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is my source schema.

```
root
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- honame: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- srcId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- srctype.: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ATTRIBUTES: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- event_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- event_datetime: string (nullable = true)
```

**I want to explode the ATTRIBUTES map type column and select all the columns which ends with _id.**

Im using the below code.

```
val exploded = batch_df.select($"event_date", explode($"ATTRIBUTES")).show()
```

I am getting the below sample output.

```
---+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|date       |                 key|               value|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|2021-05-18|SYST_id             |                  85|
|2021-05-18|RECVR_id            |                   1|
|2021-05-18|Account_Id|         |               12345|
|2021-05-18|Vb_id               |                 845|
|2021-05-18|SYS_INFO_id         |                 640|
|2021-05-18|mem_id              |                 456|
------------------------------------------------------
```

However, my required output is as below.

```
+---+-------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|date       | SYST_id      |  RECVR_id | Account_Id | Vb_id |  SYS_INFO_id| mem_id|
+----+------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|2021-05-18|  85           |  1        |   12345    |  845  |     640     | 456   |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Could someone pls assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works. You only have to add a `pivot` operation after the `explode`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

exploded.groupBy("date").pivot("key").agg(first("value")).show()
```

I assume that the combination of `date` and `key` is unique, so it is safe to take the `first` (and only) value in the aggregation. If the combination is not unique, you could use `collect_list` as aggregation function.

---

Edit:

To add `scrId` and `srctype`, simply add these columns to the `select` statement:

```scala
val exploded = batch_df.select($"event_date", $"device.srcId", $"device.srctype", explode($"ATTRIBUTES"))
```

To reduce the number of columns after the `pivot` operation, apply a filter on the `key` column before aggregating:

```scala
val relevant_cols = Array("Account_Id", "Vb_id", "RECVR_id", "mem_id") // the four additional columns

exploded.filter($"key".isin(relevant_cols:_*).or($"key".endsWith(lit("_split"))))
    .groupBy("date").pivot("key").agg(first("value")).show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, my output table should also have scrId and srctype from device struct. In the above , we have 870+ key columns,out of which I only need the  columns which ends with _split and 4 other columns. Is there any way we can pivot based on a pattern.

Comment: @SanjanaSanju I have added a few lines that might help